# Where did the definition of a positive semidefinite matrix come from?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm learning advanced Calculus, and this definition is introduced seemingly out of the blue before discussing local minima with the Hessian matrix etc. It's clear to me *how* it is used and why it *useful*, but not how one got to defining it in the first place.

I always try to see the natural progression in the material I'm studying, but this definition seems like a standalone -- I can't really see a natural progression leading towards why one might want to define such a term.

Any insights on the matter would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The definition I'm using is:

A real valued square matrix is positive semidefinite if for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have: $xAx^T \geq 0$.

Comment: There's more than one definition of positive semidefinite: which one do you mean?

Comment: it's one of the ways that matrices can be, what natural progression are you looking for? like what would an answer to this question look like, it's not very clear

Comment: @Anon I'd say that in general, the order in which tools were first developed is not usually the best order in which to learn them. For example, logarithms were first developed without it having been established that the logarithm is the inverse of exponentiation, and the MacLaurin series for the natural logarithm was around before either Taylor or MacLaurin were born

Comment: @ziggurism An ideal answer would be something like: "since we want to know .... it would be useful to look at whether the term $xAx^T$ is non-negative because ... so let's define..." where there is no logical 'jump' in the 'because...' (i.e., I won't end up asking what mad you think of *that*).

Comment: @Anon That said, I'd say that one natural justification for the definition of "positive definite" is that it is natural to ask when a function from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ is "concave up".

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, I suppose that's right. It's just somewhat disappointing to not even see how it naturally fits into the story -- even if we knew it existed, why would we want to use it here? It just seems like 'magic'.

Comment: @Anon I'd say that defining local minima is exactly the sort of context where the definition of positive definiteness emerges naturally. If you try to formulate what it means for the quadratic approximation of a function to have a local minimum, the requirement on the Hessian that you land on is precisely $x^THx > 0$ for $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characterizing local minima is a perfectly natural way to "discover" the definition of positive definiteness.

Note that in general, the local quadratic approximation for a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ about a point $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$ satisfies
$$
f(x+h) \approx Q(x + h) = f(x) + [\nabla f(x)]^T h + h^TH_f(x) h.
$$
When $x$ is a critical point of $f$ (a necessary condition for $x$ to be a local minimum), we have $\nabla f = 0$, so the above equation can be simplified to
$$
Q(x+h) = f(x) + h^TA h,
$$
where $A = H_f(x)$. Now, it turns out that if $Q$ has a strict local minimum at $x$, then it follows that $f$ will also have a local minimum at $x$. With that in mind, it would be helpful to know what property $A$ should have in order to ensure that $Q$ has a local minimum at $x$.

By definition, in order for $Q$ to have a strict local minimum at $x$, it should hold that there is some (sufficiently small) $\epsilon > 0$ for which $Q(x + h) > Q(x)$ whenever $\|h\| < \epsilon$ and $h \neq 0$.  In other words, it must hold that for all non-zero $h$ with $\|h\| < \epsilon$,
$$
f(x) + h^TAh > f(x) \implies h^TAh > 0.
$$
Note that for the quadratic form $q(h) = h^TAh$, changing the norm of the vector $h$ (while maintaining its direction) doesn't actually affect the sign of $q(h)$. Indeed, for any positive $k$, we have
$$
q(kh) = (kh)^TA(kh) = k^2 \,h^TAh = k^2 q(h),
$$
so that $q(kh) > 0 \iff q(h) > 0$. So, for a quadratic function like $Q$, having a local minimum means having a global minimum.

So, putting it all together, we find that $f$ will have a local minimum at $x$ whenever its quadratic approximation $Q$ has a strict local minimum at $x$, which occurs if and only if $Q$ has a strict global minimum at $x$, which occurs if and only if the matrix $A = H_f$ satisfies
$$
h^TAh > 0 \quad \text{for all non-zero } h \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
In other words, $f$ will have a local minimum at $x$ whenever $A$ is **positive definite**.

Answer (score 0):

We first take a vector, $x$, and then transform it with a matrix $A$. This vector is strectched and rotated. We then dot product it with the un-transformed vector. That dot product is negative if the transformation rotated the vector more than 90 degrees, or, completely changed its direction. That dot product is 0 if the transformation rotated that vector 90 degrees and that dot product is positive if the transformation rotated that vectore less than 90 degrees, or didn't change its direction much.
In the context of the Hessian, positive semi-definite means your function is only 'accelerating' your vectors in one general direction, or rather, is convex.